# How to use variable to dynamically change object attribute?

Tags: javascript

```
let property = $(this).val();
let property_name = this.dataset.property;


headObject[selected].property_name = property;
});
```

property_name is a variable not key. Are there anyway to handle this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `headObject[selected][property_name]`

Comment: After hours of searching and testing, this is exactly the answer i'm looking for! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are uing jQuery.

```
headObject[selected].attr( property_name, property ); //Where headObject[selected] is a jQuery object
```